# Why is my JavaScript if condition not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wrote the following code:

```html
<a href="#" style="min-width:100px;" class="dropdown-toggle menu__link" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn"><span class="menu__helper">Gallery</span>  <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

```js
$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
   var value = $(this)[0].innerText;
   console.log(value);
   if(value == "Gallery") {
      console.log("a");
   } else {
      console.log("b");                  
   }
});
```

First console.log prints `Gallery`. But then the if condition goes to the else statement. Why is that happening I don't understand?

Please see this image:

[image]

Comment: As a guess, the value might actually be `" Gallery"` or `"Gallery "`

Comment: No i already check. There is no space.

Comment: Well, there has to be some difference. It's not possible to say what it is, without having the actual value. You can put a debug point there and see it, or add other logs like checking what the `length` is to make sure it is 7.

Comment: nice point. thank you.

Comment: Try `value.split('').map((s) => s.codePointAt(0))` to see what the codes for each character are, and compare with the results for the string literal you’re comparing with.

Comment: Try `console.log(\`"${value}"\`)` instead. I bet there are spaces, especially given you have two spaces between your `<span>` tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$.trim` like bellow

```
$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
   var value = $(this)[0].innerText;
   console.log(value);
   if($.trim(value) == "Gallery") {
      console.log("a");
   } else {
      console.log("b");                  
   }
});
```

[image]

Comment: It's working. But can you explain me why value length is differ. I am not entering any spaces.

Comment: @Sabish.M there are two spaces between your `<span>` tags

Comment: Oh thank you. I am new to Web Development. That means innerText return spaces between tags also.

Comment: @Sabish.M use `text` method in Jquery

Comment: @Sabish.M `innerText` represents the rednered text, so it contains the space that are shown (that can be selected), so if the spaces in the html are in the `innerText` depends on various conditions.